# Bazel- How to recursively glob deleted_packages to ignore maven outputs?

Tags: bazel

I have a mutli-module project which I'm migrating from Maven to Bazel. During this migration people will need to be able to work on both build systems.

After an `mvn clean install` Maven copies some of the `BUILD` files into the `target` folder.
When I later try to run `bazel build //...` it thinks the `BUILD` files under the **various** `target` folders are valid packages and fails due to some mismatch.

I've seen `deleted_packages` but AFAICT it requires I specify the list of folders to "delete" while I can't do that for 200+ modules.
I'm looking for the ability to say `bazel build //... --deleted_packages=**/target`.
Is this supported? (my experimentation says it's not but I might be wrong). If it's not supported is there an existing hack for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Laurent's answer gave me the lead but Bazel didn't accept relative paths and required I add both `classes` and `test-classes` folders under `target` to delete the package so I decided to answer with the complete solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
#find all the target folders under the current working dir
target_folders=$(find . -name target -type d)
#find the repo root (currently assuming it's git based)
repo_root=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
repo_root_length=${#repo_root}
#the current bazel package prefix is the PWD minus the repo root and adding a slash
current_bazel_package="/${PWD:repo_root_length}"
deleted_packages=""

for target in $target_folders
    do 
        #cannonicalize the package path
        full_package_path="$current_bazel_package${target:1}"
        classes_full="${full_package_path}/classes"
        test_classes_full="${full_package_path}/test-classes"
        deleted_packages="$deleted_packages,$classes_full,$test_classes_full"
done

#remove the leading comma and call bazel-real with the other args
bazel-real "$@" --deleted_packages=${deleted_packages:1}
```

This script was checked in under `tools/bazel` which is why it calls `bazel-real` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use your shell to find the list of packages to ignore?

```
deleted=$(find . -name target -type d)
bazel build //... --deleted_packages="$deleted"
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! Do you think I can put this somehow in the `tools/bazel` script? If so do you know if everything goes through it?

Comment: I would suggest making a separate script.

Comment: May I ask why? This need is only interim (1-2 months) where maven and Bazel will be side by side and I want people to get used to Bazel and not a side script

Comment: It may be a source of confusion and complicate updates. But if it's temporary, feel free to go ahead.

Comment: I'll try (hopefully on Sunday) your proposal and then accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I don't think this is supported. Some brainstorming:

- Is it an option to point maven outputs somewhere else?
- Is is an option not to use //... but explicit target(s)?
- Maybe just remove the bad BUILD files before running bazel?

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid those suggestions aren't relevant for my use-case.